# Plotting a point on an image in Android

Tags: android, image, overlay

I have an image map, which is exactly a scaled map of a location. I have some points (x,y) on the image. I need to load this image and then, place 'dots' or pointes on this image at the (x,y) points mentioned above.

Now, When I click on these dots, I need to see a text corresponding to that image.

Ex. Suppose I have the image of a local area, and have the co-ordinates of all the shops, road etc, don't mistake it as a google map. I would load the map and then plot the shop co-ordinates on this map, and when i click on this dots, I should see the shop name. All the co-ordinates are available to me.

Can anyone help me on how to implement this in android?

Thanks

Comment: Accept some answers if you'd like more help from the SO community.

Comment: +1 and I'm in need of the same concept. update if you get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to extend the ImageView class, then override the onDraw method and use the Canvas methods (e.g., drawPoints()) to plot your points on your image.

For the click functionality, you could add a custom OnClickListener that checks if the click is on the coordinates of one of your plotted points and draws the text on the image accordingly (Canvas also includes a drawText method).

Answer (score 0):

If your are not using a GoogleMap I guess it's because it's a private map.
I would recommend you to look into [osmdroid](http://osmdroid.googlecode.com). Most of the logic you are asking is there.